# Xpath, getting substring-after "closed" at end-html tag/end-node

Tags: xpath

I want to extract information about Mortal Kombat characters, starting with their **weapons**.

Sample code:

```
<ul class="characterInfo">

<li>Name: <b> <span>Lui Kang</span></b></li>
<li>Created by: <b><span>John Tobias</span></b></li>
<li>Battle cry: <b><span><a href="/sound/mortalkombat/luikang"><u>Click here</u></a></span></b></li>
<li>Weapons: <b><span>Dragon sword and nunchaku</span></b></li>
<li>Origin: <b><span>China</span></b> </li>

</ul>
```

Using Xpath `substring-before(substring-after(.,'Weapons: '),',')` the extraction becomes

```
Dragon sword and nunchaku
                            Origin: China
```

So I am not using substring-after the correct way. I should end the extraction with the first `</span>`-node

I have tried `substring-before(substring-after(.,'Weapons: '),'&lt;/span&gt;')` but it isn't returning anything.

I think I am close, can anyone poke me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you matching literal HTML text instead of selecting the elements you want?

Comment: The weapons element (li[4] in this case) is not always at the fouth position.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. You still *never* want to try to select the literal HTML tags. By the time an XPath expression is evaluated, the literal HTML string has been transformed into a tree of abstract nodes representing the original source document and it's *that* representation that the XPath operates on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath works on the XML structure of a document, not on the raw text. If the text you want to extract is always inside a `<b>` element, you can use:

```
string(//ul[@class = 'characterInfo']/li[starts-with(., 'Weapons:')]/b)
```

The following is more universal:

```
substring-after(//ul[@class = 'characterInfo']/li[starts-with(., 'Weapons: ')], 'Weapons: ')
```

Comment: Oops, didn't see your post pop in. Same answer. Deleting mine. +1

Comment: Hm, I'm getting [INVALID XPATH EXPRESSION] on both samples.

Comment: Yes, I had some errors in both expressions. Fixed and verified.